# Como utilizar una imagen con espacios en HTML5

Tags: html

Hola estoy intentando asignar la la fotografia de un "img" sin embargo por alguna razon no reconoce las imagenes que contienen espacios en el nombre:
[image: MIREN]

Alguien sabe una forma de como arreglarlo SIN CAMBIAR EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO

Comment: deberias cambiar el titulo del problema

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, si no veo mal, estás cerrando la comilla doble antes que la simple cuando indicas la ruta de la imagen. Tendría que ser al revés:

```
onmouseover=".....src='Peliculas/A/Scoby-Doo 2.jpg';">
```